# NullPointer in AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, list, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to substitute the null value of VCID and VCIDBACKUP for "Dont Have". Here is my code:

```
if (controladorExcel == false) { 
            WritableWorkbook workbookVazio = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);


            WritableSheet sheet1 = workbookVazio.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
            TableModel model = table.getModel();

            for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Label column = new Label(i, 0, model.getColumnName(i));
                sheet1.addCell(column);
                System.out.println(column.getContents());
            }
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    System.out.println(model.getRowCount());
                    System.out.println(model.getColumnCount());
                    if(model.getValueAt(i, j) == null){ //At this point I verify if the value is null
                        model.setValueAt("Nao possui", i, j);
                    }

                    Label row = new Label(j, i + 1, //I got NULL POINTER here
                            model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                    System.out.println(row.getContents());
                    sheet1.addCell(row);

                }
            }
            workbookVazio.write();
            workbookVazio.close();
```

Here is the code of my AbstractTableModel:

```
public class MacroTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private String[] colunas;
private List<Macro> linhas;

public MacroTableModel(List<Macro> lista){
    this.colunas = new String[]{"VPN Name", "VCID", "VCID BACKUP"};
    this.linhas = new ArrayList<Macro>(lista);
}

public String getColumnName(int index) {
    return colunas[index];
}


public int getRowCount(){
    return linhas.size();
}

public int getColumnCount(){
    return colunas.length;
}


@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Macro macro = new Macro();
        switch(columnIndex){
            case 0:
                macro.setVpnName(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 1:
                macro.setVcid(aValue.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                macro.setVcid_BackUp(aValue.toString());
                break;
        }
   fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex,columnIndex);
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Macro macro = linhas.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex){
        case 0:
           return macro.getVpnName();
        case 1:
            return macro.getVcid();
        case 2:
            return macro.getVcid_BackUp();
    }
    return null; 
}



public void setColunas(String[] colunas) {
    this.colunas = colunas;
}

public String getColunas(int i) {
    return colunas[i];
}
```

}

When I debug the setValueAt method I get the correct value, but I still get the same error.
I might forgot some implementation in my AbstractModel class, I dont know exactly. Can someone help, please ?

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Macro macro = new Macro();
```

should be replaced by

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    Macro macro = linhas.get(rowIndex);
```

Otherwise, you're modifying a new Macro that is not even part of the model, and this new Macro becomes eligible to GC right after the setValueAt() method returns. You want to change the value of the Macro that is in the model, at this row index.

That said, I find it a bit strange to modify the model when exporting it to Excel. Why doesn't the model do the substitution by itself:

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Macro macro = linhas.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex){
        case 0:
           return valueOrDontHave(macro.getVpnName());
           break;
        case 1:
            return valueOrDontHave(macro.getVcid());
        case 2:
            return valueOrDontHave(macro.getVcid_BackUp());
    }
    return null; 
}

private valueOrDontHave(Object value) {
    return value == null ? ""Nao possui" : value;
}
```